# How to use decimals in HTML percentages?

Tags: html, percentage

I am currently working on a little website project of mine and I am having trouble spacing stuff out, something does not fit well and I use percentages instead of pixels to make it fit on everyone's screen, but I can't seem to find my answer on here, so that's why I'm asking it here. But now I have to use percentages, like here:

```
margin-left:4,8%
```

How do I make decimals work? Because this obviously doesn't.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Use dot as decimal character in CSS

Answer (score 2):

[CSS 2, section 4.3.3 Percentages](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#percentage-units):

> The format of a percentage value (denoted by `<percentage>` in this specification) is a `<number>` immediately followed by '%'.

[4.3.1 Integers and real numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-number):

> A `<number>` can either be an `<integer>`, or it can be zero or more digits **followed by a dot (.)** followed by one or more digits.

You are using a comma.